# offline voice input in ios app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

Now  i am developing **ios app with speech to text** using **SFSpeechRecognizer**.
It works well when internet is connected.But when no internet connection its not working as expected.Is there any way to implement speech to text functionality in offline.(Input : japanese language voice)

**Tools using for development:**

```
Visual Studio 2017 for mac
Xamarin
Xcode
c#
```

**Referrence site:**

> http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/xamarin-ios-practical-translator/

pls help to resolve my issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of 3rd-party TTS libraries available, OpenEars is just one...

Comment: @SushiHangover i want japanese language voice input.I think OpenEars not support japanese -> https://www.politepix.com/languages/

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS.

 I had never used the **SFSpeechRecognizer**. But, I have experience with making speech application using base functions in iOS. Settings -> General -> accesibility -> VoiceOver

Have you ever tried this function? This does not require the network connection.

 If it's right, i hope it helps

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: i tried but it takes input as text and speek out.But in my case speech to text

Comment: @selvarajmas  Sorry. I misunderstand your question. I search more information about your question. sorry.